# GNU Prolog simple program doesn't work as expected

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

**EDIT : I've just compiled `gprolog` from sources.**

**It works fine. The version 1.4.5 in the Debian repo is bugged.**

It's my first program in GNU Prolog (gprolog) without any success. :-(

I found these exercises in a Prolog tutorial.

```
GNU Prolog 1.4.5 (64 bits)
Compiled Feb  5 2017, 10:30:08 with gcc
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2016 Daniel Diaz
compiling /home/aubin/Dev/Prolog/overview/parents.prolog for byte code...
/home/aubin/Dev/Prolog/overview/parents.prolog compiled, 39 lines read - 2555 bytes written, 3 ms
| ?- grandPere( GrandPere, eve ).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,pere/0),grandPere/0)
| ?- parent( PereOuMere, eve ).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,pere/0),parent/0)
| ?- parents( Pere, Mere, eve).

no
| ?- parents( aubin, muriel, X ).

no
| ?- frere_ou_soeur( X, aubin ).

no
| ?- listing.

% file: /home/aubin/Dev/Prolog/overview/parents.prolog

pere(joseph, michel).
pere(michel, aubin).
pere(michel, brigitte).
pere(michel, sylvie).
pere(alain, muriel).
pere(aubin, eve).

mere(colette, muriel).
mere(muriel, eve).

grandPere(A, B) :-
    pere(A, C),
    pere(C, B).

parent(A, B) :-
    pere(A, B).
parent(A, B) :-
    mere(A, B).

frere_ou_soeur(A, B) :-
    A \= B,
    parent(C, A),
    parent(C, B).

parents(A, B, C) :-
    A \= B,
    A \= C,
    B \= C,
    pere(A, C),
    mere(B, C).

yes
```

The expected answers are :

```
grandPere( GrandPere, eve ). ==> GrandPere = michel
parent( PereOuMere, eve ).   ==> PereOuMere = aubin, PereOuMere = muriel
parents( Pere, Mere, eve).   ==> Pere = aubin, Mere = muriel
parents( aubin, muriel, X ). ==> Enfant = eve
frere_ou_soeur( X, aubin ).  ==> X = brigitte, X = sylvie
```

First line of the source is:

```
#!/usr/bin/gprolog --consult-file
```

And the invocation is:

```
$ gprolog --consult-file parents.prolog 
GNU Prolog 1.4.5 (64 bits)
Compiled Feb  5 2017, 10:30:08 with gcc
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2016 Daniel Diaz
compiling /home/aubin/Dev/Prolog/overview/parents.prolog for byte code...
/home/aubin/Dev/Prolog/overview/parents.prolog compiled, 39 lines read - 2555 bytes written, 3 ms
| ?- grandPere( GrandPere, eve ).
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,pere/0),grandPere/0)
| ?-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that invoked with a file name, `gprolog` validates it but does not load its content into the interpreter. In order to load the file content you have to use the `--consult-file` command line option:

```
$ gprolog --consult-file parents.prolog
GNU Prolog 1.4.5 (64 bits)
Compiled Jul 14 2018, 19:58:18 with clang
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2018 Daniel Diaz
compiling /private/tmp/parents.prolog for byte code...
/private/tmp/parents.prolog compiled, 31 lines read - 2474 bytes written, 9 ms
| ?- mere(muriel, eve).

yes
| ?- grandPere( GrandPere, eve ).

GrandPere = michel ?

yes
```

Read about the usage of `gprolog` on its [documentation page](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec8).

Comment: Incredible! I have'nt the same result. I have completed my question to show you the diffreences.

Comment: Yours is more recent than mine, even if the version are 1.4.5 in both

Comment: I've just compiled it from sources. It works fine. The version in the Debian repo is bugged.

Comment: I am using the macOS version installed using Homebrew.